# Set HTML Date input to default as a string

Tags: html, date

I am trying to set chart that pulls data based on an input date range, so I want to set the start and end date picker's default values to strings (i.e. "Start" "End" as opposed to "mm/dd/yyyy").

I'm currently setting up the date inputs as follows:

```html
<input style="background-color: #2E2F30; color:white; height: 50px; width: 150px;" type="date" id="StartDateSelect">
<input style="background-color: #2E2F30; color:white; height: 50px; width: 150px;" type="date" id="EndDateSelect">
<button class="btn" style="background-color: #2E2F30; color:white; height: 50px; width: 50px;" id="RefreshButton" onclick="getDates()">></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *onfocus* attribute

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start" onfocus="(this.type='date')"/>
```